# Has there ever been an open problem solved on Math.SE?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966008/is-every-irrational-number-normal-in-at-least-one-base) made me wonder if an open problem had ever been solved via collaboration on StackExchange.

Comment: Yes. There are some papers (and at least one masters thesis) which started as MSE questions/answers.

Comment: See the thread [Papers that originated on math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2970/5531)

Comment: Similar topic at MO: [Best of MathOverflow](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/617/best-of-mathoverflow)

Comment: Not solved, don't know if open problem. But many of us wonder. About [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/492326/8271).

Comment: One user gave a seemingly new proof of the irrationality of root two; not an open problem of course, but original: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917983/the-proof-of-sqrt2-is-not-rational-number-via-fundamental-theorem-of-arithm/918816#918816.

Comment: @mistermarko That is not a new proof.

Comment: You really need to provide a link to an earlier instance of it then. He genuinely thought it was new and no one could correct him.

Answer (score 29):

Ian Wanless gave an example of a pair of orthogonal complete Latin squares of order 12 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146621/91818).

The existence question was posed as a problem by Keedwell in "Some problems concerning complete Latin squares" (1974).